# php xquery parsing html

Tags: php, html, xquery

how to parse nested html tags like this structure:

```
<article class="tile">
<div class="tile-content">
    <a href=link-1">ignore</a>
    <div class="tile-content__text tile-content__text--arrow-white">
        <label class="label-date label-date--blue">01.12.2021</label>         
        <h4><a class="link-color-black" href="link-1">title-1</a></h4>
        <p class="tile-content__paragraph tile-content__paragraph--gray pd-ver-10">​
         content-1
        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="link-1" class="btn btn-link btn-link__more btn-link--arrow-right float-right">more</a>
</div>
```

```
<article class="tile">
    <div class="tile-content">
        <a href=link-1">ignore</a>
        <div class="tile-content__text tile-content__text--arrow-white">
            <label class="label-date label-date--blue">02.12.2021</label>         
            <h4><a class="link-color-black" href="link-2">title-2</a></h4>
            <p class="tile-content__paragraph tile-content__paragraph--gray pd-ver-10">​
             content-2
            </p>
        </div>
        <a href="link-2" class="btn btn-link btn-link__more btn-link--arrow-right float-right">more</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

to array like:

```
 $parsedArray = [
    0 => 
    ['title => 'title',
     'link' => 'link-1',
     'date' => '2021-12-01',
     'content' => 'content-1']
    1 => 
    ['title => 'title-2',
     'link' => 'link-2',
     'date' => '2021-12-02',
     'content' => 'content-2']
,....]
```

i use xquery like above, but this remove all tags, after that i have only implode text from all tags, i need to extract info from all tags, any tip?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html['html']);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $nodelist = $xpath->query("//article[contains(@class, 'tile')]");

    foreach ($nodelist as $n) {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($n);
        echo '</pre>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump` won't parse the DOM :)

You just need to re-query for your elements within the `tile`, then assign them to the array.

Assign a working item array to define the structure if it matters, else just build up the result as you go.

```
<?php
$str = '<article class="tile">
    <div class="tile-content">
        <a href=link-1">ignore</a>
        <div class="tile-content__text tile-content__text--arrow-white">
            <label class="label-date label-date--blue">02.12.2021</label>         
            <h4><a class="link-color-black" href="link-2">title-2</a></h4>
            <p class="tile-content__paragraph tile-content__paragraph--gray pd-ver-10">
             content-2
            </p>
        </div>
        <a href="link-2" class="btn btn-link btn-link__more btn-link--arrow-right float-right">more</a>
    </div>
</article>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtml($str);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//article[contains(@class, 'tile')]") as $tile) {
    // define item structure
    $item = [
        'title' => '',
        'link' => '',
        'date' => '',
        'content' => ''
    ];
    
    // find date
    $query = $xpath->query("//label[contains(@class, 'label-date')][1]", $tile);
    if (count($query)) {
        $item['date'] = $query[0]->nodeValue;
    }

    // find link/title
    $query = $xpath->query("//h4/a[1]", $tile);
    if (count($query)) {
        $item['link'] = $query[0]->getAttribute('href');
        $item['title'] = $query[0]->nodeValue;
    }
    
    // find content
    $query = $xpath->query("//p[contains(@class, 'tile-content__paragraph')][1]", $tile);
    if (count($query)) {
        $item['content'] = $query[0]->nodeValue;
    }
    
    // assign
    $result[] = $item;
    
    // cleanup
    unset($item, $query);
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => title-2
            [link] => link-2
            [date] => 02.12.2021
            [content] => 
             content-2
            
        )

)
```